# how to make non-monospace font string right align in java

Tags: java, fonts, alignment

I met a strange requirements:***let the non-monospace font right align***,is there are some way to do it?how can detect the actual length for the non-monospace font string?

Answer (score 0):

use the class FontMetrics provided by

```
FontMetrics myFontMetrics = myGraphics.getFontMetrics()
```

the call

```
int width = myFontMetrics.stringWidth(myString);
```

gives you the string width in pixels, which you can subtract from your drawing coordinate.

Comment: your solution is for used for java swing application,but my project is a pure javaSE project,is there any way to do it?

Comment: my solution only requires you to have a Graphics object, this can also be the graphics of an BufferedImage for instance.

Comment: ,I want to let the file in the my harddisk to right align,so how can I get an Graphics instance?

Comment: ,I want to let the file in the my harddisk to right align,so how can I get an Graphics instance